# R python javascipt integration

Tags: javascript, python

I am faced with building a front end application for a scientific project, where the original scripts come from R and python. I found this interesting framework called OpenCPU(https://www.opencpu.org/) which claims to provide a seamless integration between R and javascript.

Now I am faced with the issue for python and javascript integration. Are there any good frameworks for this? Please help with suggestions?

P.S.(converting the python script to R script is ruled out since the python script depends on external libraries specific for python)

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't run python on client side, you can either port it yourself or use a compiler/converter. [Here's some python to javascript compilers](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/list-of-languages-that-compile-to-js#user-content-python):

- [PYXC-PJ](http://pyxc.org/) [CS friend] Python to JS. Can generate a (line/col)-number mappings file.
- [Pyjamas](http://pyjs.org/) Python to JS.
- [Pyjaco](http://pyjaco.org/demo) Python to JavaScript compiler with module support.
- [Pyjs](https://github.com/anandology/pyjs) Python to (readable) JS.
- [Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/) Python. Client side.
- [PyCow](https://github.com/p2k/PyCow) Python to MooTools JS.
- [PyvaScript](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django/2010/07/PyvaScript-Pythonic-syntax-for-your-browser) Python-like syntax to JavaScript.
- [RapydScript](https://github.com/atsepkov/RapydScript) JavaScript with a Pythonic syntax.
- [Brython](http://brython.info/) browser python
- [PythonScript](http://apppyjs.appspot.com/) Python-like compiled to JavaScript
- [pythonscript](https://github.com/DenerosArmy/pythonscript) Python compiled to readable JavaScript using  the AST. (proof of concept)
- [PythonJS](https://github.com/PythonJS/PythonJS) Integrates several python to js methods into one project. Very Active.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) protocols out there, usually the problem is the other way around - Python is well supported but R isn't.

I wouldn't completely rule out [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface) in this scenario.  Just be sure to keep the number of round-trips required to an absolute minimum.  It's a very old and simple idea - the request comes in and the web-server runs an instance of Python or R - whichever the requested script requires, and returns the output.  [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is a likely to be a very good choice of output format as it can easily be written by both Python and R, and consumed by JavaScript.

Given that Django is well regarded Python web-framework and Shiny is a well regarded R web-framework - neither of which I know anything about - I'd be inclinded to find out what they have to offer before committing myself to introducing a third language, JavaScript, into the mix (even though it is by far my favourite language of the three).